# Check python list for predefined matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pattern-matching

Im a Python beginner and I wondered if anyone could advice me on how to check a list for pre- defined number of pairs.

```
green = yellow and blue 
purple = blue and red 
orange = red and yellow 
grey = white and black 
beige = white and yellow 
brown = black and yellow
```

These are a number of example list that I would like to iterate through and check if any of the above pairs exist in it. If they do exist in the list then I would like to return the name of the pair.

```
Lists: 
List1 ['white','black','yellow'] (return: brown, beige)
List2 ['yellow','white','black','red'](return: beige, grey, orange)
List3 ['blue','yellow','red'] (return: green, purple)
List4 ['white','red','blue'] (return: purple)
```

I have tried to filter lists by their length and then check membership of each element so far but it does not return all possible pairs.

Thank you for your help!

These are the things that I have tried so far: 
(1) loop through each list and test for every item (this however does not return all possible solutions)

```
if "white" and "yellow" in list1:
    result = 'beige'

elif 'yellow' and 'black' in list1:
    result = 'brown'

else: 
result = 'None'
```

(2)

```
len_of_list = len(lists) 
if len_of_list == 3:
three = lists
for item in three:
        if any (colour in three for colour in ('yellow','black')):
            print(three)
```

(3)

```
if len_of_list ==3: 
    three = lists
    first_el = three[0]
    second_el = three[1]
    last_el = three[-1]

if "yellow" in first_el and "black" in second_el:
           result = 'brown'

elif 'yellow' in first_el and 'black' in last_el:
    result = 'brown'

elif 'yellow' in second_el and 'black' in last_el:
    result = 'brown'
```

Comment: You said that you tried to filter. Can you share those attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function uses a dictionary of the secondary colours and their component colours, and checks if the set of component colours is a subset of the set of colours passed to it:

```
secondary_colours = {"green": ("yellow", "blue"),
                     "purple": ("blue", "red"),
                     "orange": ("red", "yellow"),
                     "grey": ("white", "black"),
                     "beige": ("white", "yellow"),
                     "brown": ("black", "yellow")}

def obtainable_colours(primary_colours):
    """Returns a list of secondary colours obtainable
    from combinations of the primary colours provided.
    Assumes additive pigment mixing as defined above."""
    global secondary_colours
    response = []
    for s_col,components in secondary_colours.items():
        if set(components) < set(primary_colours):
            response.append(s_col)
    return response
```

Test:

```
p1 = ['white','black','yellow'] 
p2 = ['yellow','white','black','red']
p3 = ['blue','yellow','red'] 
p4 = ['white','red','blue']

for p in [p1,p2,p3,p4]:
    print(p)
    print(obtainable_colours(p))
    print("\n")

>>>

['white', 'black', 'yellow']
['grey', 'beige', 'brown']


['yellow', 'white', 'black', 'red']
['orange', 'grey', 'beige', 'brown']


['blue', 'yellow', 'red']
['green', 'purple', 'orange']


['white', 'red', 'blue']
['purple']
```

Comment: Thank you so much - I completely forgot about dictionaries in my confusion looking at different solutions!!!